# What happened to kiheitai after war?

Tags: gintama

In *Gintama*, did they explain anything about after war life of Takasugi?.

I was curious to know about that, after knowing the after-war life of Sakamoto and Katsura and of course Gintoki. But they didn't explain much about how Takasugi lived his life after the war and how Bansai and Makato joined Kiheitai.

In "Silver Soul" Arc, they did explain how they met which seems just after the war. But still, they didn't explain some like how Takechi is feminist and not lolicon and when did Bansai and Otsu meet (after the war).

Or did I miss this?

Comment: Have you completed the Silver Soul Arc?

Comment: @PJTheMADAO I have completed Silver Arc (After this post, sorry for posting before that I didn't expect them really explain). It did answer some parts. but still, it didn't answer some like why takechi became feminist and how bansai and otsu met.

Comment: I have to assume you're asking only about Takasugi (based on the title), but the addition on the question body about Takechi, Bansai, and Otsu could make this question not focused due to multiple questions. Could you clarify the question?

Comment: specifically kheitai but mainly takasugi.